# if stops checking true/false after first match

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a if statement where I want to run a function on three fields.

The problem is that the if stops checking the rest of the statement after the first hit, meaning that the rest of the fields that are empty wont get the css class which indicates a problem to the user.

This is the function that checks if the selected field is empty

```
function emptyCheck(field) {
    if(!field.val().trim()) {
      field.addClass("validation");
      return false;
    }else {
      field.removeClass("validation");
      return true;
    }
  }
```

This is where the checking function is run (part of a larger function)

```
if(type == "Book") {
  if(!emptyCheck($("#height")) ||
     !emptyCheck($("#width")) ||
     !emptyCheck($("#length"))) {
      return false;
      }else {
        if(!dimensionCheck()) {
          return false;
        }else {
          allGood = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Change `||` to `&&` if you want all conditions required in an `if`.

Comment: An alternative would be to convert your `emptyCheck` so it accepts multiple fields:  `function emptyCheck(fields) { fields.each((field) => { ..your code...}` (plus a bit more to get the true/false overall that you require) and then pass in multiple fields by class, `if (!emptyCheck($(".required")))...` or make it a full plugin and use `if (!$(".required").emptyCheck())`

Comment: @freedomn-m Funny that you mention that. I myself thought about making the function accept multiple fields, but I thought that it would involve adding 3 parametrs and then writing separete if's for each case 1param, 2, etc. Using .each sure is simpler haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid the short-circuiting behavior, of one call's `return false` resulting in the subsequent calls not starting at all.

Call all `emptyCheck`s first, putting the return values into an array, and *then* check that array for whether any of its values are false.

```
if (type == "Book") {
    const results = ['height', 'width', 'length'].map(str => emptyCheck($('#' + str)));
    if (results.includes(false)) {
        return false
    } else {
        // all are true - continue with desired logic
    }
```